# Java - read Excel csv and print them -changed- new

Tags: java, excel, csv

Could someone tell me why Eclipse is giving me the error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedWriter.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
at javadruckdruck.main(javadruckdruck.java:52)
```

I can not get it. I proofed it like ten times, but it will not work.

```
import java.io.*;                      


public class javadruckdruck {

    public static void main(String[] args)   throws IOException
    {



        //scanning
        FileReader       fr = new FileReader ("fax_user.csv")     ;
        BufferedReader   br = new BufferedReader (fr)             ;
        FileWriter       fw = new FileWriter("Druckausgabe.txt")  ;
        BufferedWriter   bw = new BufferedWriter (fw)             ;
        String textnow      = br.readLine ()                      ;
    //  bw.write (Email);
    //  bw.close();

        while (textnow !=null) {


        //Umlaute gegen ae,oe,ue tauschen
        String text = textnow                                     ; 

        String textXreplaced   = text                             ;
        textXreplaced          = text.replace ("ä","ae")          ;
        String textXXreplaced  = textXreplaced                    ;
        textXXreplaced         = textXreplaced.replace ("ü","ue") ;
        String textXXXreplaced = textXXreplaced                   ;
        textXXXreplaced        = textXXreplaced.replace ("ö","oe");
        String textXXXXreplaced= textXXXreplaced.replace("ß","ss");
        textXXXXreplaced       = textXXXreplaced                  ;

        //Text umformatieren, splitten, E-Mail, Nummer anhängen
        String textreplaced = textXXXXreplaced.replace(" ", "")   ;
        String textreplacedtwo = textreplaced.replace("\"","")    ;
        String textreplacedthree = textreplacedtwo.replace(";","");
        String [] parts     = textreplacedthree.split("[,]")      ;
        String part1        = parts[0]                            ;
        String part2        = parts[1]                            ;
        String part3        = parts[2]                            ;
        String Email        = "@bogestra.de"                      ;
        String Zahlen       = ";3"                                ;
        String finished     = part3 + "." + part2 + Email + Zahlen + part1;
        textnow             = br.readLine ()                      ;

        bw.write (finished);
        bw.close();     



        //System Ausgabe      
        //System.out.println(part3 + "." + part2 + Email + Zahlen + part1 );


    }





        br.close();

    }


    }
```

Comment: what line is line 52?

Answer (score 0):

You close bw inside of the loop. You should move the line outside of the loop:

```
  public static void main(String[] args)   throws IOException
    {



        //scanning
        FileReader       fr = new FileReader ("fax_user.csv")     ;
        BufferedReader   br = new BufferedReader (fr)             ;
        FileWriter       fw = new FileWriter("Druckausgabe.txt")  ;
        BufferedWriter   bw = new BufferedWriter (fw)             ;
        String textnow      = br.readLine ()                      ;
    //  bw.write (Email);
    //  bw.close();

        while (textnow !=null) {


        //Umlaute gegen ae,oe,ue tauschen
        String text = textnow                                     ; 

        String textXreplaced   = text                             ;
        textXreplaced          = text.replace ("ä","ae")          ;
        String textXXreplaced  = textXreplaced                    ;
        textXXreplaced         = textXreplaced.replace ("ü","ue") ;
        String textXXXreplaced = textXXreplaced                   ;
        textXXXreplaced        = textXXreplaced.replace ("ö","oe");
        String textXXXXreplaced= textXXXreplaced.replace("ß","ss");
        textXXXXreplaced       = textXXXreplaced                  ;

        //Text umformatieren, splitten, E-Mail, Nummer anhängen
        String textreplaced = textXXXXreplaced.replace(" ", "")   ;
        String textreplacedtwo = textreplaced.replace("\"","")    ;
        String textreplacedthree = textreplacedtwo.replace(";","");
        String [] parts     = textreplacedthree.split("[,]")      ;
        String part1        = parts[0]                            ;
        String part2        = parts[1]                            ;
        String part3        = parts[2]                            ;
        String Email        = "@bogestra.de"                      ;
        String Zahlen       = ";3"                                ;
        String finished     = part3 + "." + part2 + Email + Zahlen + part1;
        textnow             = br.readLine ()                      ;

        bw.write (finished);



        //System Ausgabe      
        //System.out.println(part3 + "." + part2 + Email + Zahlen + part1 );


    }
        bw.close();     




        br.close();

    }
```

Comment: //starting at textnow                                       bw.write (finished);
      bw.flush ();
           
            
            
           
   
   
  }
   
   bw.close(); 
   br.close();
 
  }


  } Still an error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at javadruckdruck.main(javadruckdruck.java:46)"

Comment: @SteffenLehnhardt Looks like you have a line with less then 3 parts. Mybe a blank line at the end? You chould check this, before access the part with index.

Comment: Do you mean in the .csv file?

Comment: @SteffenLehnhardt Yes

Comment: 001, "Sommer, Klaus" They are formated like that in an Excel file from A1 to A1000, where should the blank line there? After 1000? And when yes, how do it stop it from there?

Comment: @SteffenLehnhardt it is a guess. add if (parts.length<3) { System.out.println(textnow);} else { String part1        = parts[0]; ...;bw.write (finished);}. Then you will see on console whick line causes the problem